# Python BST code returning None instead of array?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I'm running a BST in Python, with the following code:

```
def findOdd(head):
    ary = []
    ary = BST_size(head, ary)
    print ary
    return ary

def BST_size(root, ary2):
    if root is None:
        print ary2
        return ary2
    if root.data % 2 != 0:
        print "yes"
        ary2.append(root.data)
        BST_size(root.left, ary2)
        BST_size(root.right, ary2)
    else:
        BST_size(root.left, ary2)
        BST_size(root.right, ary2)
```

As you can see, the goal is to return an array of the odd values within the array, however, when I run it, ary2 equals an array of the odd values, but ary simply equals None. 
EDIT:
I changed to code to this and I'm still getting an error:

```
def findOdd(head):
    ary = []
    print BST_size(head, ary)
    return BST_size(head, ary)


def BST_size(root, ary2):
    if root is None:
        return ary2
    if root.data % 2 != 0 and root.data not in ary2:
        ary2.append(root.data)
        BST_size(root.left, ary2)
        BST_size(root.right, ary2)
    else:
        BST_size(root.left, ary2)
        BST_size(root.right, ary2)
```

Comment: Because your function returns `None` for the last `if`..`else` blocks. When you do not specify `return something`, `None` is returned by default.

Comment: @ettanany How to fix it still will not work

Comment: You need to return something, for example `return BST_size(root.right, ary2)`

Comment: But I can only return one I cannot do:

Comment: return         BST_size(root.left, ary2)
    return    BST_size(root.right, ary2)

Comment: @ettanany I only get one return

Comment: Take a step back and think about *why* you are making two recursive calls to `BST_size`.

Comment: @ettanany To get both sides of the tree

Comment: You can do `return val1, val2`, but in this case I am not sure whether it is possible or not!